# Sort the sentence based on the word length

Tags: c++

I am newbie programmer C/C++. Was learning pointers and character pointers and was trying to solve an exercise problem. Problem statement

Given a sentence " World is a great place to live in"

Problem description: Rearrange the given sentence based on the ascending order of its word length

output should be " A is in to live world great place"

I am trying my best and am pasting the code that I wrote, but not able to arrive at the answer. Can somebody point out the errors. I am sure there are lots.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
char* breakIntoWords(char *,char*pt);

    int getwordcount(char* p)
    {
     int wc = 0;

     while(*p == ' ')
      {
         p++;
      }
      while( 1) {

      while( *p != ' ' && *p != '\0' && *p !='\n')
      { 
        p++;

      }
    if(*p ==  ' ')
    {
       p++;
    }
    else{
       break;
    }


      wc++;
      }
    wc++;
      return wc;

    }

    int main()
    {

       char bsentence[120][5];
       char sentence[120];
        cout<<"Ent&er STring"<<endl;
        char *p ;
        p = "Test it again and welcome";
        strcpy(sentence, p);
        int wordcount =0;
        wordcount=getwordcount(sentence);
        char *pt = sentence;
        for(int i =0; i <wordcount; i++)
        {

         pt = breakIntoWords(pt,bsentence[i]);
        }



           for(int i =0; i< wordcount; i++)
        {
          for(int j=i; j<i;  j++)
           {
              int one = strlen(bsentence[i]);
              int two = strlen(bsentence[i+1]);

            if(one > two)
               {
                   char temp[120];
                   strcpy(temp,bsentence[i]);
                   strcpy(bsentence[i+1],temp);


           }

            }

        }
    char sen2[12];
     for(int i=0; i<wordcount; i++)
      {

          strcat(sen2,bsentence[i++]);
          strcat(sen2, " ");
       }
       strcpy(sentence,sen2);




        cout<<sentence;

    }
    char* breakIntoWords(char*p, char*pt)
    {
       int i =  0, j = 0;
      while( *p != ' ')
      {
       pt[i] = *p++;
       i++;

      }
      p++;
      pt[i]='\0';

      return p;
    }
```

Without using String class.

I have solved it finally. Any inputs on improving it is welcome.

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 30
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 100
using namespace std;

int getWordCount(char* s)
{
   int wc = 0;
   while(*s == ' ')
     s++;
   while(*s != '\n')
   {
      while(*s != ' ' && *s != '\n')
      {
         s++;
       }

       if(*s == ' ')
       {
         while(*s == ' ')
            s++;
       }
       wc++;
   }
   return wc;
}
char* getWord(char* Source, char* word)
{
     while(*Source == ' ')
         Source++;
      int i =0;
      while(*Source != ' ' && *Source != '\n')
      {
         word[i] = *Source;
         Source++;i++;
       }
       word[i]='\0';
       if(*Source == ' ')
       {
         while(*Source == ' ')
            Source++;
       }
       return Source;


}
void sortSentence(char* p[], int wc)
{
   char *temp = new char[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
   for(int i =0; i<wc; i++)
   {
      for(int j = i; j< (wc-1); j++)
       {
           if(strlen(p[j]) > strlen(p[j+1]))
            {
                strcpy(temp,p[j]);
                strcpy(p[j],p[j+1]);
                strcpy(p[j+1],temp); 
             }
        }
    }
    delete[] temp;
}
int main()
{

 char* string;
 string = new char[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
 cout<<"Enter Sentence"<<endl;
 fgets(string,MAX_LINE_SIZE,stdin);
 int wordCount = getWordCount(string);
 char* pArrayOfPointers[30];
 char* tempString = string;
 for(int i =0; i< wordCount; i++)
 {
    char *ptemp;
      ptemp =new char[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    pArrayOfPointers[i]= ptemp;
    tempString = getWord(tempString,pArrayOfPointers[i]);
    cout<<pArrayOfPointers[i]<<endl;          
  }
  sortSentence(pArrayOfPointers, wordCount);

  strcpy(string,pArrayOfPointers[0]);
  strcat(string," ");
  for(int i =1; i< wordCount; i++)
  {
     strcat(string,pArrayOfPointers[i]);
     strcat(string," ");

   }
   cout<<string;
 delete[] string;


}
```

Comment: There are a couple of conventions you should be aware of: 1) try to format your code correctly-- inconsistent braces and random whitespace just make things hard to read. 2) Don't just dump your code and say "what's wrong?", tell us what's not working, and what you've tried.

Comment: Hint: You can write less code by using multisets!

Comment: Since you're using strcpy and strcat, I assume you're allowed use standard library functions - look into using strtok to separate the input string, strlen to get the lengths

Comment: Removed C tag as the OP is clearly writing in C++.

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe that in `C++` one has to include `cstring` and not `string.h`. Can anyone confirm ?

Comment: @ereOn: nothing stops you from including the legacy C headers, but the new `<cxxxx>` headers have several advantages (the identifiers they provide are put in the `std` namespace and there are overloaded definitions for some of the standard C functions).

Comment: Hi All,  I was trying to implement the solution using C features. I agree I have used cout but that is only for the convenience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is vastly more complex than necessary because you’re not decomposing the problem into smaller tasks that would be easier to tackle.

Basically there are three steps:

1. Decompose sentence into an array of words.
2. Sort array of words by length.
3. Output words, separated by spaces.

Each of these tasks is trivial in C++ and doesn’t require pointers or anything like that (which is a *good* thing. Pointers have their place in C but only rarely in C++).

For example, the first step can be solved using C++ IO streams and the `vector` container:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;

std::string word;
while (cin >> word)
    words.push_back(word);
```

This reads individual words from the standard input and stores them in a vector.

The second step <del>can</del> *should* be solved using the C++ standard library [`sort`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function.

The third step is a mere matter of iterating over the vector and pushing the words to the `cout` stream.

All in all, this shouldn’t take more than 15 lines of code.

If you don’t want to use a `string` class, your first step should be to write one. It doesn’t have to be fancy, but it should at least take care of the rudimentary mechanisms of handing the string’s memory, reading from input and writing to output.

Comment: +1 for the general approach.  He specified that he couldn't use `std::string`, but the basic principle of decomposition still applies.

Comment: I agree about breaking the task into smaller tasks, but if the point is to learn about pointers and arrays, then the OP should *not* use `vector`. Every student should learn to handle the old tools before advancing to the new ones.

Comment: @Beta “Every student should learn to handle the old tools before advancing to the new ones” – Sorry but this is the wrong approach to learning. I know that a lot of people claim learning must be bottom up but these people have no clue whatsoever of didactics.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. I am a capable engineer and scientist and an accomplished teacher (although I admit I had to look up "didactics"). I wouldn't require a C/C++ student to learn the slide rule or assembler language, but I would require an exercise like this, at least once. I've lost count of the engineers I've worked with who used the latest, fanciest tools and always made a mess of things because *they didn't understand the underlying logic*.

Comment: @Beta But the order is wrong. First learn the high-level tools, *then* how their intestins work. After all, school children don’t start with Peano’s axioms in mathematics, or quantum mechanics in biology. They start with high-level processes that are easily understood and applied before broadening and deepening their knowledge.

Comment: I think we're agreeing. This is why we have *subjects*. Pointers and arrays are the innards of the STL containers, but they are also part of the language; you can be a great biologist without knowing quantum (or even if quantum weren't real), but if you don't know pointers and arrays then you aren't a competent C++ programmer. So since you have to learn them, you'd better learn them first because a) they're simpler and b) they help you understand (and appreciate!) advanced data structures, but not the other way around. And don't get me started on woodworking analogies...

Comment: @Beta and @Konrad. I was doing it only using C features and hence no strings. I agree I used cout, for convenience of printing.

Comment: @Konrad I used your approach but did it using only C feature.